# How to filter by Attribute set using $this->getAttributes();

Tags: magento, filter, optional-parameters, getattribute

I am currently using this code for displaying all attributes.

```
$attributes = $this->getAttributes();
```

I want to know how to filter it by Attribute Set, Input type and other attribute options.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use

```
$products->addAttributeToFilter('attribute_set_id','33');
```

here, 33 is your attribute set id.

 for example,

```
$collection = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->getCollection();

$collection->addAttributeToFilter('status', array('eq' =>1))

       ->addAttributeToFilter('attribute_set_id','33')
       ->addAttributeToSelect('*');
```

Comment: okey. for that you can use
`$attributes = Mage::getModel('catalog/product_attribute_api')->items($attributeSetId);
foreach($attributes as $_attribute){
    print_r($_attribute);
}`

Comment: I could use this code to display attributes that matched. Thank you so much

Comment: Welcome...enjoy :)  **No Thanks, Just Helping Hands**